# Android Float Slide Windows

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, menu, slide

Im trying to make a design in my app for android but yesterday I found a serious problem what is delaying my development. Here is the Issue, I want so draw a float menu who contains a List view

[image]

As you can see, Windows 1 is not compressed, it must be clear, the windows 2 is showed from the right side, but I want only show a small part of it, like 10 px  more or less. When the user want slide the windows 2, the windows 1 must not move, must be statics.

[image]

And when the usser move the Windows 2 to the left, this windows must be quiet for see the list what contains.

This is all, how can I do this thing? how can I control the movement of the windows transparencies each moment and if the windows 1 contains the map, how can I draw the second 2 for don't overload the fingers interaction?
Thank you so much, I hope your answers

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the library SlidingMenu it's currently used in some awesome Android apps. some of them:
Foursquare
LinkedIn

Check from [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/) and try from [PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example)